# Best way to rename MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xaml

In Visual Studio 2010, if I create a new project that is a WPF Application, the `MainWindow` subclass of `Window` is provided as a default first window. The steps I've been taking to rename `MainWindow` are:

- Use Solution Explorer to rename `MainWindow.xaml`.
- Rename the class in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`.
- Select the "Rename 'MainWindow' to ..." option from the "Options to update references to the renamed object" popup menu which appears next to the renamed class.
- Update `StartupUri` in `App.xaml` accordingly.

Is there a better way? :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1. Get ReSharper
> 2. Use [Rename](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Rename)
> 3. ????
> 4. Profit

Comment: Perhaps you mean ReSharper? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to ReSharper Anurag. Didn't know about it. Unfortunately, I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express, which doesn't appear to be supported by ReSharper.

Comment: @dharmatech Edited :).  Yes Express does not support addin.  If you really want it to be easier you can try [SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/pages/FeatureTourRefactoring.aspx)... I have no experience with it, but have read good things.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of a better way. An alternative which may result in less steps could be to create a new window and then set the StartupUri to the name of your new window.

It is then up to you whether you want to keep MainWindow or delete it (which would make sense if you are not using it at all).

Answer (score 2):

Visual C# 2010 Express Has a built in option to solve this.You can see the menu bar has an option "Refactor" where you can see two sub-menu Rename and  Refactor.To change any name you just have to take the cursor on the name(Calculater in image) and click right button.Then go to Refactor and click Rename.You will see a dialog box comes and then you put the new name you want to give to your attribute.

[image]

Comment: Hello @MohammadAsad. Yes, that feature will rename the method. However, it appears that, in the case of `MainWindow`, you'll still have to up date `StartupUri` manually. But it's good that you mention this feature, for completeness.

Comment: This actually works well as long as you do things in the right order. 
1. Refactor/Rename class 
2. Rename the file in Solution Explorer 
3. Replace the StartupUri in App.xaml with new name

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Resharper for .NET](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

[image]

[image]

It will take care of all referencing to the MainWindow (including **App.xaml**)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a really old question, but it has a really simple answer if you are looking to just change the title of the window. No Resharper or changes to multiple locations needed.

In MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window ... Title="Alloantibody Exchange">
```

or in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Title = "Alloantibody Exchange"; //<-- Just do this!
    }
```